# EasyMock missing behavior even though it's defined

Tags: java, junit, easymock

No matter what I do, I get the following error when trying to mock a method

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: missing behavior definition for the preceding method call:
>   ConfigurationSection.get("country-language")
>   Usage is: expect(a.foo()).andXXX()

My code for testing:

```
EasyMock.expect(section.getString("country-language")).andReturn("US");

LocaleManager.updateLocale(section, Collections.emptyList());
EasyMock.expectLastCall();

replayAll();

Assert.assertEquals("Test", TranslatedMessage.translate("test"));
verifyAll();
```

The expect andReturn is called for the mocked class, and the static upateLocale method calls the method, first thing.
The strange thing is this test works fine:

```
EasyMock.expect(section.getString("country-language")).andReturn("US");
replayAll();

Assert.assertEquals("US", section.getString("country-language"));
verifyAll();
```

But calling it from an external method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mock says:

```
EasyMock.expect(section.getString("country-language"))
```

The error says:

```
ConfigurationSection.get("country-language")
```

You are not mocking `get("country-language")`. You are mocking `getString("country-language")`.

Unrelated, but `verify` is a maintenance nightmare and should generally be avoided. This ties test code directly to an implementation. Tests should focus on inputs and outputs if at all possible.

Comment: I forgot my own implementation, and it was under my nose the whole time! Thanks for the help, I spent hours trying to get anything working.

Comment: I just realized the thing is I had the same method earlier with PowerMock, and I guess my code just defaulted to the right value. Gotta fix the test to the non-default language.